# :not() selector not working

Tags: html, css, less

I have a layout that has tabs, with an accordion inside and another set of tabs inside that. Inside each inner tab I want to have a set of checkboxes. When I put them in and style them up there's a conflict between them and the CSS for the outer tabs. So I've used the not selector so that the input styles for the tabs won't be applied to the checkboxes, but it hasn't been applied.

Here's a CodePen that shows the issue: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/WebDevelopWolf/pen/VzgKzW)

```css
.wrap-tabs {
  section {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  input:not(.squaredFour) {
    display: none;
  }
  label:not(.squaredFour) {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bbb;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  label:hover:not(.squaredFour) {
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  input:checked+label:not(.squaredFour) {
    color: #555;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 2px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  #tab1:checked~#content1,
  #tab2:checked~#content2,
  #tab3:checked~#content3,
  #tab4:checked~#content4 {
    display: block;
  }
}

.access-privilages {
  padding: 10px;
}

.access-privilages .tabContent {
  padding: 10px;
}

.access-privilages .panel-heading a:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\2212";
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin-right: 8px
}

.access-privilages .panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\2b";
}

.access-privilages .panel-group .panel+.panel {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.access-privilages .panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.access-privilages .panel {
  border: 0 none;
}

.access-privilages .panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body {
  border-top: 0 none;
}

.access-privilages .panel {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.access-privilages .panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: @dark-subtle;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: @primary;
}

.squaredFour {
  position: relative;
  label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  label:after {
    content: '';
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  label:hover::after {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap wrap-tabs">
  <h4>Portal Settings</h4>
  <a ng-click="job.back()" class="backlink"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i> Go Back</a>
  <h1>Settings</h1>
  <p>Modify your portal-wide settings here</p>

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Delivery Rules</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Collection Rules</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Global Settings</label>

  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i> Account Settings</label>

  <section id="content1">
    <h4>Delivery Rules</h4>

    <div class="access-privilages">
      <!-- Accordions -->
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_hradmin">Economy</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse_hradmin" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">

              <!-- Tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                  <a id="personal" href="#tabContent_personal">Monday</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="financial" href="#tabContent_financial">Tuesday</a></li>

              </ul>
              <div class="tabContent" id="tabContent_personal">
                <h4>Monday</h4>
                <div class="squaredFour">
                  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" checked />
                  <label for="squaredFour"></label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="tabContent" id="tabContent_financial" style="display: none;">
                <h4>Tuesday</h4>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_rmgadmin" class="collapsed">Next Day</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse_rmgadmin" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <!-- Tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                  <a id="nd-monday" href="#nextday-monday">Monday</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="nd-tuesday" href="#nextday-tuesday">Tuesday</a></li>

              </ul>
              <div class="tabContent" id="nextday-monday">
                <h4>Monday</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="tabContent" id="nextday-tuesday" style="display: none;">
                <h4>Tuesday</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    <h4>Collection Rules</h4>
  </section>

  <section id="content3">
    <h4>Global Settings</h4>
  </section>

  <section id="content4">
    <h4>Account Settings</h4>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: Soooo, the selector is :not() working? haha ... sorry. Bad Joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.squaredFour` class is applied on `div` not on `label` i.e. there is not `label` or `input` with `.squaredFour` class. There are 2 ways of solving this

Add `.squaredFour` to the `input` and `label` on which you don't want to conflict the `css` rules.

OR if you don't want to add class then change the css for `:not` as in snippet.

```css
input:not(.squaredFour > label) {
  display: none;
}

label:not(.squaredFour > label) {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="labelFour" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" checked />
<label for="squaredFour" class="labelFour"></label>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because `:not` relates to element it's used on. Your `label` doesn't have `.squaredFour` class, but it's parent (`div`) has. You should add a class to your `label` or change

```
label:not(.squaredFour)
```

to

```
*:not(.squaredFour) label
```

It will apply to every `label` which is not a descendant (any level) of element with class `.squaredFour`.